# How to create a different class than the one invoked?

Tags: python, class, warnings

Ok. I have been struggling with phrasing this question.
I have a subclass. I want it to create an instance of its base class if certain things are true when it is invoked. Would I do this with __ new __ ? If so how would i?

this is an example of what I mean:

```
import warnings
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.val = list(args)
    def __str__(self):
        return "A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args)==3:
           A.__init__(self, *args)
           return
        else:
            warnings.warn("Making an A object!")
            return A(*args)

    def __str__(self):
        return "B"
    def extramethod1(self):
        print "This method is only in a B object"

x = B(1, 2, 3)
Warning (from warnings module)
  File '/test.py', line 14
UserWarning: Making an A object!
y = B(1, 2)
print x, y
'A B'
y.extramethod1()
'This method is only in a B object'
```

Also, how would I have B issue a warning when it does this?

Comment: Where is the constructor of B? You should define the init logics there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a class constructor return a subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433584/should-a-class-constructor-return-a-subclass)

Comment: You are not making an A object! You make both times a B object.

Answer (score 1):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433584/should-a-class-constructor-return-a-subclass/12433588#12433588).  That one is asking this in the reverse direction: whether a superclass should return a subclass instance.  The answer is the same, though: use a factory function instead.

Comment: Factories are common and expected in this kind of situation.  Also, it seems dirty to have code like `my_instance = B(1, 2, 3)` then call `isinstance(my_instance, B)` and see the answer `False`!!

Answer (score 0):

__init__ should return None! Not the object!

You could try a different approach:

```
def f(*largs,**kwargs):
    if (...):
        return A(*largs,**kwargs)
    return B(*largs,**kwargs)

x = f(1,2,3) 
y = f(1,2)
```

You could eventually make f a staticmethod of B so to have it binded to the class

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your motives for doing that, in Python, whenever you make a call to create  a class instance, what is called is this:

the `__call__` method on the class's metaclass. That is usualy " `type.__call__`  - very few uses of custom metaclasses override this.

That function, in turn, calls the class's `__new__` object. `__new__` returns an object which is the instance created - it can be from the class called, it  s superclass, a subblass, or any other Python object. (Including `None` which happens soemtimes when one forget to include  a proper `return` statement in a `__new__` method.  The metaclass's `__call__` them calls the `__init__` method on the new object.

For your purposes, the easy way to go is just to write your `__new__` method, and make it return wathever you find more apropriate. Note that the return value of `__init__` is always ignored (and thus should be the implicit `None` not to mislead anyone reading the code).